# Reset a Checkbox Field Clientside

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a checkbox control and a reset button on a web page. I want the chekbox to be unchecked whenever the rest button is pressed. This should be a clientside process.

How can i achieve it? can it be done by using document.getelementbyID()?

Answer (score 1):

Could try something like the following.

```
$get("<%=checkbox.ClientID%>").checked = false;
```

or for easier understanding since `$get` just references `document.getElementById` you can use

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById(<%=checkbox.ClientID%>),
    button = document.getElementById(<%=button.ClientID%>);

button.onclick = function(){
    checkbox.checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With plain javascript,  you can do it like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkYes" checked="checked"  /> Yes <br/>
<input type="button" id="btnReset" value="reset" onclick="UnSet();" />
```

Script

```
function UnSet()
{ 
    document.getElementById("chkYes").checked=false;
}
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/cF6pN/6/

if you are already using jQuery in your page, you can do like this

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnReset").click(function(){
       $("#chkYes").removeAttr('checked'); 
    });    
});​
```

Assuming you have your HTML like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkYes" checked="checked"/> Yes <br/>
<input type="button" id="btnReset" value="reset" />​
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/hNm6k/2/

Comment: yes.. lets add jQuery just to set a checked property. jQuery all the things!!

Comment: Man... using jQuery for such a basic task is overkill ._.

Comment: add jquery.js as well, if you don't have then download and add it..  @Shyju code will work for u..

Comment: Totally agree that we should not add jQuery for this simple thing. But if you already have the library loaded, we should use that. I didn't notice the tags. Updated my answer with non jQuery version.